# Using devise method 'current_user' in mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

am relatively new to rails,i have been working with devise authentication gem for a while now,but my problem is,my app sends an email,with the firstname and lastname of the current user after a form is filled,but each time i try to send the email with the above stated parameters i get an error that says "undefined method current_user"
my mailer looks like this,note:its a separate controller that controls it.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>name</td><td><%= current_user.firstname %><%=current_user.firstname  %></td>
```

```
<tr>

        <td>phone no.</td><td><%= current_user.phone %></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td>location</td><td><%= @device.location %></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td>device type</td><td><%= @device.device_type %></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td>brand</td><td><%= @device.brand %></td>

    </tr>

</table>
```

my controller action is this

```
def create

    @user=current_user

    @device = Device.new(device_params)

        if @device.save

            DeviceMailer.send_device.deliver

            flash[:notice] = 'Request sent successfully,you will be
```

contacted shortly'
            else
                flash[:error] ='Request not sent,check details and sendagain'
                render 'new'
            end

```
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`current_user` is a method that is available only to views and controllers.  If you want to use it in a mailer or model, it will have to be explicitly used as an argument for the mailer method.

Inside the controller create method:

```
DeviceMailer.send_device(current_user, @device).deliver
```

Mailer method:

```
def send_device(user, device)
  @user = user
  @device = device
  # More code as needed
end
```

Mailer view:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>name</td>
    <td><%= @user.firstname %><%= @user.firstname  %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>phone no.</td><td><%= @user.phone %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>location</td><td><%= @device.location %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>device type</td><td><%= @device.device_type %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>brand</td><td><%= @device.brand %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: but @device.location shows this error "undefined method `location' for "      but @current_user is fine.i followed your example though but its the same error @Ben Y

Answer (score 0):

current_user is set when you login.  In order to force the user to login before the user can execute a controller action you need to have the following line at the top of your controller:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```